# what is the replacement for Apache spark in IBM watson studio services as now it is deprecated

Tags: apache-spark, ibm-cloud

I was creating a recommendation engine in IBM Watson studio for that I needed to add spark service but now it is deprecated what I should use now.

Answer (score 0):

You should utilize spark environments for your Watson studio project.
You can define that spark environment using Environments tab in project and then utilize that runtime when you create notebook or change service for existing notebook.

Answer (score 0):

@Veer as @charles said Spark services are now accessible via Environments. When creating a notebook select a Spark compatible environment and import pyspark in your notebook.

[image: spark options]